# Looking for an API for backing up SMS messages

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms

Is there an API available that can be used to make an application for backing up SMS messages in WP7?
I have been looking for this for a long time but haven't found any satisfactory answers. I am trying to find either a direct API or indirect (i.e. a REST API) if one exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for devices with an 'interop' unlock, but you won't get the app through the marketplace submission process.

That said, There's a working SMS backup tool here [SMS Backup](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1448197) that may be what you're looking for / help you learn how to achieve it from a technical perspective.